# Makefile make untarring rule dependent on untarred files

Tags: makefile, tar

Let's say I have a tar file which has file1.c and file2.c within it.  Now, I have a makefile which must untar the files, and build them.  I can't build until the untar is complete, of course, and I don't want to untar on subsequent builds unless someone wipes out the .c files, or updates the tar file itself after the last successful untar.  Finally, if someone presses ^C before tar is complete, I need it to run again on the next make.

So I have Makefile1:

```
untar: file.tar.gz
    tar -xzmf $?
    echo > $@

file1.c file2.c : untar

build: file1.c file2.c untar
```

So, now I run `make build` for the first time.  It untars (and date stamps) file1 and file2, creates the untar file (which is just a dummy file which lets me know when the last untar ocured).  If I then remove file1.c, it will not untar again, because the file untar is newer than file.tar.gz.

So, we go to Makefile2:

```
untar file1.c file2.c: file.tar.gz
    tar -xzkmf $?
    echo > $@

build: file1.c file2.c untar
```

I run `make build`.  It will now try to run the tar -xzmf recipe three times: once for file1, once for file2, and once for untar; this is also not good.  I could also create a phony target to do the untar, and make untar, file1, and file2 dependent on it.  The problem is that phony targets are always run, and I don't want to untar every time.  Another complication would be that the untar file is newer than the file1.c and file2.c (as it is updated after the tar is complete), which can make dependencies somewhat complicated.

Can someone suggest a good solution to this problem?

Comment: This is similar to what is discussed in http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/rules-multiple-outputs-gnu-make, except in this case you may not be able to use a pattern rule, because the untar target will likely not match the pattern.  If you need the untar target, and can't rename it to a matching pattern, you can't do what you're trying to do with Make.

Comment: @John I know this is old, but I was hoping you might still be lurking and had found an answer or had a workaround you might share, I would love to know if so.